# What is the only Jutsu included in the manga from Filler Episodes of Naruto Shippuden Anime

Tags: naruto

My friend challenged me with this question a while ago.

Which jutsu premiered in Naruto Shippuden, but was thereafter picked up by Masashi Kishimoto into his Manga?

This has apparently only happened once, all the other jutsu's happened the other way.  He created them and put them into the Manga, then were disseminated into the Shippuden

Comment: You only have a title here, there's no question in the body. Please [edit] this to give a little more detail about what you're asking

Comment: Didn't figure I'd need a question in the body when the title question covered all of the important aspects, like the full question. But I have modified it to have a somewhat copy of the question in the body.  Hope that clears it up

Comment: Your edit makes a substantial difference in understanding what you're asking for. The body clarified it and I'd be surprised if this stayed closed now.

Comment: Why is this still on hold?  I've edited the question to further clarify what I was asking.

Comment: My guess is simply that it's not received enough attention (likely due to the major holiday season). You can post on [meta] asking for it to be evaluated, and I brought it up in chat for you.

Answer (score 1):

The only jutsu that matches somehow the requirements (at least to my knowledge and search) is the [Water Release: Water Shuriken (Suiton: Mizu Shuriken)](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Water_Release:_Water_Shuriken):

[image]

This jutsu appeared first in [Naruto: Shippūden #412 - Neji's Judgment](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Neji%27s_Judgment) which aired in Japan on May 14, 2015 and was later also used in the Naruto novel [Gaara Hiden: A Sandstorm Mirage](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Gaara_Hiden:_A_Sandstorm_Mirage) which was published in Japan on June 4, 2015.

However this is a novel and not the original manga although is was illustrated by Masashi Kishimoto.